# How would I add a space character to ascii_lowercase

Tags: python, encryption, append, ascii

So im making a code that'll encrypt a character or word per se. Im done with that so far but would like to include a space character and continue on with an extra word to encrypt. "Congratulations you won"<<<

```py
from random import shuffle
from string import ascii_lowercase
array=[0]*26

for i in range(26):
    array[i]=i
shuffle(array)
let=ascii_lowercase
get=input("Give me a word to encrypt: ")
encrypt=""


for i in range(len(get)):
    
    ind=ord(get[i])-97
    
    print(get[i],ind,array[ind],let[array[ind]])
    
    encrypt=encrypt+let[array[ind]]
print(encrypt)
```

Code above

Something i would want would be like this

```
Give me a word to encrypt: congrats
c 2 6 g
o 14 22 w
n 13 9 j
g 6 5 f
r 17 19 t
a 0 25 z
t 19 14 o
s 18 1 b

y 24 13 f
o 14 22 w
u 20 15 e

w 22 12r
o 14 22 w
n 13 9 j

gwjftzob fwe rwj
```

i don't expect those exact results as its meant to be randomized/ shuffled

I attempted to use `.append` and `.join` to include space in `ascii_lowercase` but failed :')

Comment: What's the point of `let.find(get)`? You don't assign the result to anything.

Comment: that was me trying more solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `+` to concatenate strings.

```
let = ascii_lowercase + " "
```

Then replace `ord(get[i]) - 97` with the value of `let.index(get[i])`, since that formula only works for lowercase letters.

You also need to increase the length of `array` to 27, to add a place for the encrypted spaces.

```
from random import shuffle
from string import ascii_lowercase

array=list(range(27))
shuffle(array)

let=ascii_lowercase + " "

get=input("Give me a word to encrypt: ")
encrypt=""

for c in get:
    ind=let.find(c)
    if ind != -1:
        print(c,ind,array[ind],let[array[ind]])
        encrypt += let[array[ind]]
    else:
        # if it's not a letter or space, don't change it
        encrypt += c

print(encrypt)
```

Comment: i get list index out of range in line 18 where it says ``` print(get[i],ind,array[ind],let[array[ind]])```

Comment: `ord(get[i])-97` only works for letters.

Comment: whats the best way to include the space then if ord can't be included. I put it there originally so i could get the encryption to work

Comment: I put the full code into the answer.